# Will using open GL in android application reduce the system efficiency?

Tags: android

I have heard that a processor without graphics card will take a lots of time to produce a 
graphical entity,than one with graphics card.
So is there anything like that if we use Open Gl in android application??
will my application become slow ??

Answer (score 0):

Without a GPU/hardware accelerated video, the graphics would be calculated/drawn/rendered with the CPU (software rendering). This will definitely be slower than having a GPU, as GPUs are more suited at processing/displaying graphics like with OpenGL.